# How do I init XOD in WebViewer? "DisplayModes" is undefined

Tags: pdftron

I'm trying to load a XOD document into a PDFTron WebViewer. As far as I can read in the documentation and samples, this should be a simple "plug and play"-operation - it should simply work when you point at a file. Ideally, in my example, the document should be fetched from a service, as so:

```
fetch('/myservice/GetXOD')
.then(function(data) {
    $(function() {
        var viewerElement = document.getElementById("viewer");
        var myWebViewer = new PDFTron.WebViewer({
            initialDoc: data.body
        }, viewerElement);
    });
});
```

Unfortunately I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'DisplayModes' of undefined
```

The reason I'm doing it in a `fetch`, is because I'm rendering a Handlebars template, and pass the data to instantiate in a callback. However, I've isolated the code into an otherwise "empty" HTML-document, and in the simplified example below, I'm simply pointing at the XOD provided by PDFTron on page load (no `fetch` this time).

```
$(function() {
    var viewerElement = document.getElementById("viewer");
    var myWebViewer = new PDFTron.WebViewer({
        initialDoc: 'GettingStarted.xod' // Using the XOD provided by PDFTron
    }, viewerElement);
});
```

This unfortunately returns a different error (HTTP status 416).

```
Uncaught Error: Error loading document: Error retrieving file: /doc/WebViewer_Developer_Guide.xod?_=-22,. Received return status 416.
```

The same error appears when I run the samples from PDFTron on localhost.

I'm at a complete loss of how I should debug this further - all the samples assume everything is working out of the box.

I should note that I can actually get PDFs working just fine on localhost, but not on the server. XODs are problematic both on the server and on localhost.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry to hear you are having troubles running our samples.

Your error message says 416 which means "Requested range not satisfiable". Perhaps your development servers do not support byte range requests (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_serving).

Could you try passing an option `streaming: true`? When streaming is true you're just requesting the entire file up front which shouldn't be a problem for any servers but it is a problem for WebViewer if the file is large because it will need to be completely downloaded and parsed at the start which is slow.